# Dynamic ListView Templates

Tags: asp.net, listview

I'm using a ListView to display a set of input controls which are database driven.  The database tells me the name of the input value and its type, and I have my ListView properly displaying a set of rows of input controls based on this information.

What I'd like to do is have a set of rows, with each row housing N input controls, until there are less than N controls to house, and then just those.

So, if the total is 10, and N is 3 then output would look like this:

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
x
```

I thought I'd accomplish this through ItemTemplate/alternatingItemTemplate, but now I'm not sure how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item/Alternating item template will not help you .  Have a look at `GroupTemplate` and `GroupSeparatorTemplate`.  Set`GroupItemCount="3"` in the `ListView` start tag, and put your repeated input control in the `GroupTemplate`. Then use `<br/>` element as your separator.

An alternative would be to use a table and have the `GroupTemplate` specify a table row, with the repeated element being a table cell.  Here's a link to MSDN material on the topic, which shows how to do a tiled layout using a table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.grouptemplate.aspx